# State where unique solution exists for IVP

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm self teaching differential equations and came across this question from a book that I was reading.

Consider the problem
$$yy''=-(y')^2$$
$$y(0) = y'(0) = 1$$

(i) Show that the problem has a unique solution on an interval containing 0.

(ii) Find the solution and state where it exists.

I've used Picard's theorem to show (i). With the second part, I've found that the solution is $\frac{1}{2}y^2 = x + \frac{1}{2}$ but I'm not sure how to go about finding where it exists. I've tried sketching the graph, and I think that due to the initial conditions, maybe would only work for y>0, but am not sure. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: what happens to your solution when $x < -1/2$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $y^{2}/2=x+1/2$ then $y^{2}=2x+1$ and $y=\pm\sqrt{2x+1}$ with interval of existence only if $2x+1\geqslant0$ that is for $-1/2\leqslant x<+\infty$.